How To Prevent Caching a Nextjs App Router Page?
I have seemingly tried everything and nextjs still caches server data. I am using the app router.
// app/users/page.tsx
import React from "react";
import ManageUsers from "@/modules/users/components/ManageUsers";
import AccessDenied from "@/components/AccessDenied";
import { fetchData } from "@/lib/fetchData";
import { User } from "@/modules/users/types";

export const revalidate = 0;
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';


interface FetchUserDataResponse {
  users: User[];
}

export default async function UsersPage() {
  const { data, error, isForbidden } = await fetchData<FetchUserDataResponse>(
    `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_URL}/api/private/users/fetch-users`
  );

  if (isForbidden) {
    return <AccessDenied />;
  }

  return <ManageUsers users={data?.users || []} error={error} isForbidden={isForbidden} />;
}

route:
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { Users } from 'node-appwrite';
import { createAdminClient } from '@/lib/appwriteAdminClient'; // Adjust the import path as needed
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';
export const revalidate = 0;

export async function GET(req: NextRequest) {
  // Create the Appwrite client using the helper function
  const { databases } = createAdminClient();

  // Initialize the Users service with the admin client
  const usersAPI = new Users(databases.client);

  try {
    // Fetch the user list from Appwrite
    const usersList = await usersAPI.list();

    // Map the users list to the desired format 
    const users = usersList.users.map((user) => ({
      name: user.name || 'N/A',
      email: user.email,
      phone: user.phone || 'N/A',
      emailVerification: user.emailVerification,
      phoneVerification: user.phoneVerification,
      isAdmin: user.labels.includes('admin'), // Check if 'admin' label exists
    }));

    // Create a response with cache-control headers to prevent caching
    const response = NextResponse.json({ users });
    response.headers.set('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate');
    response.headers.set('Pragma', 'no-cache');
    response.headers.set('Expires', '0');
    response.headers.set('Surrogate-Control', 'no-store');

    return response;
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.error('Error fetching users:', error);
    
    // Create an error response with cache-control headers to prevent caching
    const errorResponse = NextResponse.json({ users: [] }, { status: 500 });
    errorResponse.headers.set('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate');
    errorResponse.headers.set('Pragma', 'no-cache');
    errorResponse.headers.set('Expires', '0');
    errorResponse.headers.set('Surrogate-Control', 'no-store');

    return errorResponse;
  }
}

As you can see my page and my route have export const revalidate = 0; and export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';. I'm setting all the headers.
Here is my fetch data helper:
// lib/fetchData.ts
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';
export const revalidate = 0;
interface FetchDataResponse<T> {
    data: T | null;
    error?: { message: string; status: number };
    isForbidden: boolean;
}

async function fetchWithAuth(url: string, options: RequestInit = {}): Promise<Response> {
    const sessionCookie = cookies().get('session')?.value;

    const headers = {
        ...options.headers,
        cookie: `session=${sessionCookie || ''}`,
        'Cache-Control': 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate',
        Pragma: 'no-cache',
        Expires: '0',
    };

    const fetchOptions: RequestInit = {
        ...options,
        headers,
        next: { revalidate: 0 },
        cache: 'no-cache',
    };

    return await fetch(url, fetchOptions);
}

export async function fetchData<T>(url: string, options: RequestInit = {}): Promise<FetchDataResponse<T>> {
    let data: T | null = null;
    let error: { message: string; status: number } | undefined;
    let isForbidden = false;

    try {
        const response = await fetchWithAuth(url, options);
        const result = await response.json();
        console.log(result)
        if (!response.ok) {
            if (response.status === 403) {
                isForbidden = true;
            } else {
                error = { message: result.error || "Failed to fetch data", status: response.status };
            }
        } else {
            data = result;
        }
    } catch (err: any) {
        error = { message: err.message, status: 500 };
    }

    return { data, error, isForbidden };
}

I have tried everything I found and nothing works. It won't re-fetch the data on route change. It fetches once on page load and never again. I am trying to get fresh data each time a user visits this page.

Can't you use "use client" in the or use export const revalidate = 0 to revalidate the data?

Seems like the revalidation doesn't work in the headers because the call was cached as static rendering. Also you could try: export const fetchCache = 'force-no-store' as per https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config#fetchcache
